# Div tag alignment in slds

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I am trying to display two column table format where my first column is lengthy and second column content is very less. I am using the below code to display but since first column is lengthy(vertically) second column content is aligning at the center. How could I align the content in the second div to the top

```
<form class="slds-form--inline">
   <div class="slds-form-element">
      //this table has multiple rows so this div element is vertically lengthy 
      <table>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        .
        .
        .  
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="slds-form-element" >
      Text here which should align to the top form
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can try enclosing the text in a span and use vertical-align: top; for the 2nd div

Comment: what about using `slds-align-top` within `slds-grid`? look here: [Grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/grid/#overview)